# When import math is written twice, is a reference created during the second import math statement?

Tags: python, math, import, module

**CASE 1**:

```
import math
import math
```

**CASE 2**:

```
import math
from math import sqrt
```

When `import math` is written twice, is a reference created during the second `import math` statement? Can someone please explain to me how does this happen in both the above cases in detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imported modules are stored in `sys.modules`. If they are needed again by another `import` or `from ... import ...` they are taken from there.

In case 1, line 2 does nothing. More precisely: It takes the stored `math` module and sets `math` in surrounding namespace to reference to module again.

In case 2, line 2 looks up the already loaded `math`, retrieves `sqrt` from it and places it in the surrounding namespace.

Update:
An example to show that a second import of the same module overwrites the name in surrounding namespace (usually with the same reference but this can be changed):

```
import sys
import re

import math
print(math) # nothing unusual: <module 'math' ...

sys.modules["math"] = re
print(math) # nothing unusual yet: <module 'math' ...

import math
print(math) # What?: <module 're' ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"**sets math** in surrounding namespace to reference to module again."*?

Comment: The namespace can be seen as dictionary (sometimes it is one). On first import the name (key) "math" is created and set to reference the module. The second import sets the now existing name "math" again to the same module object reference. This happens because in theory the module object in `sys.modules` could have changed and "math" would then reference the new module.

Comment: So the name ```math``` refers to the module object, right? And when you say *"...sets the existing name math"*, do you mean that the memory address(*in the case of CPython*) of the module object is set once again?

Comment: Yes, there is a memory address pointing to the object which is meant with "math". On the second import the memory address is overwritten.

Comment: I have added an example to show that a second import does not do really nothing but reassigns the name (usually to the same module but this can be changed).

Comment: Does the same thing happens when I write ```a = 1; a = 1```?

Comment: Yes, the object reference (aka memory address) to which name "a" refers is overwritten.

Comment: Hey, why isn't the output of ```print(math)``` ```<module 're'...>``` after ```sys.modules["math"] = re```? I didn't understand.

Comment: @NSR The surrounding namespace is separate from the `sys.modules` dictionary. The namespace is modified by the `import` but not earlier.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please explain this in detail?

Comment: @NSR The variable named "math" is independent of the key "math" in `sys.modules`. Only the `import` copies the module reference from the second to the first.

Comment: Okay, so they both are in different namespaces. Now,  I understood the first six lines, but how ```math``` is changed to ```re``` in the last two?

Comment: @NSR The `import math` looks up what is stored as referenced module for "math" in `sys.modules`. It takes this reference, whatever module it is and copies it to the "math" in the namespace. But when asking the module to show a representative string with `print(math)` it reveals its real name (which is also stored separately in the module object).

Comment: Okay, so what happens is that if I write ```print(sys.modules['math'])``` after ```sys.modules["math"] = re```, I can see ```<module 're' from...>```. So when I do ```import math``` for the second time, it just copies the reference to the ```math``` in the namespace of my main file, right? But I did not understand how do name such as ```math``` work as a reference in Python?

Comment: *"which is also stored separately in the module object"* - So is the namespace which is created a part of the module object?

Comment: @NSR A namespace can be imagined as dictionary which stores a name as key and a reference to an object as value. There are multiple namespaces. One for each module (but this has nothing to do with the module name which is also stored somewhere in the data of a module object), also one for each class and each function (actually each function invocation).

Comment: *"...but this has nothing to do with the module name which is also stored somewhere in the data of a module object"* - Does each Python object has its name stored somewhere in the object? Isn't a namespace represented as a hash table in memory?

Comment: @NSR Only a few objects like modules or functions store a name. A namespace implementation can be a hashtable but doesn't have to be. This discussion is now far away from the original question and I can't explain all details how Python works, sorry.

Comment: Last question: Which objects do not store name? I am assuming that you are talking about the ```__name__``` attribute.

Comment: @NSR The `__name__` attribute is the usual way to access the name but only things like functions, classes and modules have one. Simple objects like strings, lists and most objects in the standard library and other libraries don't.